# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

Tags: java, android, release

I'm trying to build my release apk and Android Stdio gives me error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\azats\Desktop\App\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\maindexlist.txt --output C:\Users\azats\Desktop\App\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Users\azats\Desktop\App\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\release\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

I cleaned and built the project multiple times, but it didn't work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`defaultConfig {multiDexEnabled true.....}`
and to avoid dex error in certain kitkat devices
 `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`

to your app/build.gradle

you might want to take a look at:
[Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: I had already added multiDexEnabled true to my build.gradle. But I still get the error.